# Adapt height of the elements based on siblings height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a couple  of widgets in line depending on  screen size. Here is my layout:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="name">
      Block name
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Some description goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="name">
      Block name
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Some very long description goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="name">
      Block name
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Some description goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and  styles are the following:

```
.widget {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  //height: auto;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px silver solid;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  color: #082654;
}

.description {
  color: #4AB6E1;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/audssc1v/)

[image]
The problem is that I want to be  them  of certain height: e.g.80px, cause its the size that will look  nice for almost all cases, but rarely I have some longer content inside widget description and then it goes out of the box. So in this case I'd like its height to adapt to content size and all other widgets to its height too. When I  set widgets height to  auto - only  single  widget stretches in  height and they look uneven. Any ideas how to change the styles so that to  achieve what I  need?

Comment: how about using `display:table-cell`

Comment: `min-height: 80px;`

Comment: @dNitro, It makes only one widget to  adapt its height

Comment: [Would one of these ideas work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19695851/3585500)

Answer (score 1):

I you can use jQuery look at this JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cnoof9hb/

Uses the following to set the height:-

```
var maxheight = 0;

$('div div.widget').each(function () {
    maxheight = ($(this).height() > maxheight ? $(this).height() : maxheight); 
});

$('div div.widget').height(maxheight);
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect time for [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), I've made a container div to surround all 3 elements and given it `display: flex;` I've also given `display: flex;` to each div bellow that (as these are the bits that need to change size).

Have a look

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  display: flex;
  width: 33.33%;
}
.widget {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px silver solid;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.widget .name {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  color: #082654;
}
.widget .description {
  color: #4AB6E1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="widget">
      <div class="name">
        Block name
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Some description goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="widget">
      <div class="name">
        Block name
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Some very long description goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="widget">
      <div class="name">
        Block name
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        Some description goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using diplay:table

```css
.widget {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  //height: auto;
  height: 80px;
  display:table;
  border: 1px silver solid;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  color: #082654;
}

.description {
  color: #4AB6E1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="name">
      Block name
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Some description goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="name">
      Block name
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Some very long description goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="name">
      Block name
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Some description goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: else u can find the height using jquery, and assign that height to other divs

Comment: I' d rather not use javascript

Comment: try with like above display:table

Comment: it seems it doesn't help https://jsfiddle.net/audssc1v/2. I tried it and  it makes only single widget to  adapt not all the others

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` to float an element to make the parent element take the cumulative height of it's childrens' height. Also `height:auto;` to be used in the parent element, as the height is unpredictable.

```css
.widget {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: white;
      /*height: auto;*/ /* removed this */
      border: 1px silver solid;
      font-size: 18px;
  
      /* Added these 2 lines */
      float:left;
      height: auto;
    }

    .name {
      font-weight: bold;
      height: 40px;
      color: #082654;
    }

    .description {
      color: #4AB6E1;
    }
```

Comment: this would help, but  I  still want the widget to be of the height 80px when the description fits in one line. Do you  have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it does "Adapt height of the elements based on siblings height" but you may need to change it little bit to suit ur needs

```
<div class="t-row">

    <div class="col">Some description goes here Some description goes here</div>

    <div class="col">on goes here</div>

    <div class="col">here</div>

    <div class="col">Some description goes here Some description goes here Some description goes here Some description goes hereSome description goes here Some description goes here</div>

</div>
```

and css

```
.t-row{
    display: table-row;
}
.col{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

see fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ubLqjeq/)